# How to use virtualenv project in other machine/environement

Tags: python, python-2.7, virtualenv

I created a project in virutalenv with all libraries installed. So, when I move the virtualenv directory to new machine/environment, How do I get it work? And in new machine what needs to be installed apart from standard python?

I have all referece of directory and import refering to virtual env only.

I know this is very basic question. But, I was not able to find answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't move your virtualenv since it is essentially linked to your system python and the binary won't necessarily work on other machines.

However, you can export a list of installed packages and install them in another virtualenv through a `requirements.txt` file.

```
# Generate a requirements file
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

On the new machine, first create a new `virtualenv` and then install the packages by using the `requirements.txt` file as a reference.

```
# Install the packages
pip install -r requirements.txt
```